# Automatically start animation in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, animation, windows-8, blend

So I created an animation with a storyboard in blend that basically displays an image pulsing or basically changing the opacity to 10% then back again. The problem I am having is that I 'save all' changes in blend but when run the app in visual studio the animation does not run.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there another action I need to activate to get this to run or there is there code I am forgetting?

Comment: post some code, have you written `ObjectOfStoryBoard.Begin()` anywhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add storyboard.Begin(); for each item...stupid mistake on my part but it is solved now!